# Generating paypal buttons for other users dynamically

Tags: php, paypal

I am planning on letting people list and sell their items on my site with payment/transaction processing done via paypal. To do this, i plan on letting my users dynamically generate a paypal button of their own when they are uploading their items(using my upload form).

I know that i can generate paypal buttons **for my own account** simply by logging into my paypal account. However, how would i go about doing this for other people ( if possible), whose accounts i will not have access to, and how would i make it secure?

Inputs would be appreciated!

P.S Im coding the site in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have your users customize a PayPal button to their own needs, right?

If so, what you should do is store the user's email address and the image button they want to use in a database (like MySQL) and then retrieve it and print the HTML.

Here's an example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`, `items` WHERE users.id = items.user_id") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $row['currency']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['item_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
<input type="image" src="<?php echo $row['button_image']; ?>" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

[Here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside) is some very brief documentation from PayPal on it.